# bash: how to take a screenshot of gnome-terminal/terminator/xterm's screen output

Tags: bash, terminal, screenshot, xterm, gnome-terminal

I want to capture the output of a linux command in a terminal like terminator/xterm

But the output goes 3-4 pages scrolling.

Just like in chrome we have an "Full page screen Capture" by https://gofullpage.com/ which can capture a webpage running multiple pages

Similary can we first take screenshot and then scroll and take screenshot and keep doing it till i  meet the end of the terminal

Is there some tool in terminator or xterm to do this

Comment: Do you want the *screenshot* to be in a picture format or just plain text?

Comment: picture only. I want to see as it is